# Derivative of inner product of function of matrices

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am working on an optimization problem where I have to find derivate of $⟨F(X),WF(X)Z⟩$ with respect to X. Here $⟨,⟩$is a standard inner product (Frobenius dot product), W & Z are a constant matrix, and $f$ a function of a matrix, whose output is also a matrix. I have previously asked a slightly different version of the same question, below is the solution for it 
 \begin{align}
\phi &= \langle F,WF \rangle = \langle W,FF^T \rangle\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &=  \langle W,dF F^T+FdF^T\rangle\\
&=\langle W+W^T,dF F^T\rangle\\
&= \langle (W+W^T)F,\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\rangle
\end{align}
I am working on slightly modified problem, but I have not been able to come up with such compact answer. Here is link [Derivative of inner product of matrix-valued functions of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507820/derivative-of-inner-product-of-matrix-valued-functions-of-matrices) to my previous question

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just made the changes.

Comment: One difficulty is that the derivative of $F$ with respect to $X$ is a 4-dimensional matrix.

Comment: I thought for simplicity, initially, $X$ can be taken a scaler. This could give a good idea how the solution behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of typing, I'll use the product notation 
$$A:B=\langle A,B\rangle$$
Then consider the derivative with respect to a single element of the independent matrix, $X_{ij}$, which is a scalar quantity.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= F:WFZ \cr
d\phi
 &= dF:WFZ + F:W\,dF\,Z \cr
 &= (WFZ + W^TFZ^T):dF \cr
}$$
For ease of typing (once again), I've used the notation
$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{ij}}$$
To obtain the full matrix result, sum over all of the $\{i,j\}$ indices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_\alpha(\epsilon)$ be the derivative of $f$ at $\alpha$.
Then the derivative of the composite function $g$ at $\alpha$ as a function of $\epsilon$ ought to be $\newcommand{\ang}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}\ang{D_\alpha(\epsilon),Wf(\alpha)Z}+\ang{f(\alpha),WD_\alpha(\epsilon)Z}$. By the product rule or something. Frankly I can't be bothered to put in effort, when you've already asked an almost identical question, and haven't shown any work in the question you wrote above.

Comment: I apologize, I just modified the question to include the previous questions' solution.